# How to extract complete Product name using regex or x-path

Tags: jmeter

I have an Html page which contains many script tags and inside each script tag I have a structure like:

```
<script>window.pagedata={listItems:[{"name": "Multi-Warna Lembut Silikon Casing Ponsel Untuk Apple iPhone 11 Case 11 Pro Max Tidak Berbau dan Tidak Beracun Casing iPhone 11 pro-Max"}]}</script>
```

My goal is to extract all the `name` from this script tag using a regex or a x-path in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract name using below regular expression. Please note that if your requirement is to extract any one product name from response (assuming you have lot of product names in response), you can put match No. as "0" (which selects randomly). Else, if you need product name which comes at first occurrence, you can define match no as "1".

Regular Expression : \{"name": "(.*?)"\}

If your goal is to extract all names, then please use "-1" in match No. Variable substitution will be ${name_1}, ${name_2} ..etc;

[image: Regular Expression]

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

Answer (score 0):

You can use regulare expression extractior post processor and refer to the regex as shown below.

[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the names, you're looking for
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `name`
   - Regular Expression: `{listItems:\[{"name":\s*(.+?)"`
   - Template: `$1$`
   - Match No: `-1`

     [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to access the extracted values as `${name_1}`, `${name_2}`, etc.

Demo (assumes [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/) to mimic multiple products)

[image]

More information: [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)